# Does Google Sign-in SDK iOS support iOS6?

Tags: ios, ios6, google-signin, dyld

My project must support iOS6.

I use Google Sign-In SDK v2.4.0.
But When I selected Target , the GoogleSignIn.framework (optional) in Xcode project and run on the iOS6 device, dyld log tells

***dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSessionConfiguration.***

Is there how to use this in iOS6 Device??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GoogleSignIn guides](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start) don't state a minimum SDK version however...

`NSURLSessionConfiguration` was introduced in iOS7 so if you are getting that issue when trying to link to the SDK then iOS 6 certainly isn't supported.

Checking out the sample project (`pod try Google`) and it also has the Deployment target set to iOS 7.0 so it looks like you are out of luck I am afraid. Maybe look at using an older version but I can't help you with what version supports iOS 6 and I would not know if it is still supported/maintained by Google.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have realized that for supporting google sign-in, I must increase minimum iOS Version to iOS7.0 or Later.

Comment: Does that mean minimum requirement version is iOS 7? Hopefully Google can make it clear on any SDK released. And hopefully it would support iOS 6..

Comment: @neobie Yes it does. You're right though, they should have made it clearer